# Use nested query in XPath to retrieve multiple informations of the same node

Tags: xml, xpath, nested

I'm using XPath to retrive informations about the elements in my document based on my XML Schema.
Here is an example of an element:

```
 <image id = "000003">
        <info>
            <name> Hut Weber - Hitler Chaplin</name>
            <description>
                L'immagine raffigura il volto di Hitler e quello di Charlie Chaplin uno di fianco all'altro (stilizzati).
            </description>
            <company> Hut Weber </company>
            <resolution width = "992" height = "680"/>
            <typeOfAd category = "brand"/>
        </info>
        <rhetoric>
            <framework_1>
                <complexity complexityType = "juxtaposition" degree = "low" value = "0.8"/>
                <richness richnessType = "opposition" degree = "high" value = "0.5"/>
                <explanation>
                    <element name = "Adolf Hitler" position = "../immagini_annotate/000003.jpg#138,194,252,282"/>
                    <element name = "Charlie Chaplin" position = "../immagini_annotate/000003.jpg#566,119,318,358"/>
                    <relationship>
                        La pubblicità vuol fare intendere quanto un cappello possa fare la differenza, 
                        in quanto la silhouette a sinistra può essere associata sia alla figura di Hitler che a quella di Charlie Chaplin, 
                        mentre la silhouette a destra è chiaramente quella di Charlie Chaplin, inconfondibile grazie al suo cappello. 
                        Si lavora per giustapposizione di due immagini e opposizione dei soggetti raffigurati.
                    </relationship>
                </explanation>
            </framework_1>
        </rhetoric>
      </image>
```

There are many elements like this (same structure). I want to be able to retrieve, for example, the name of the images with the complexity attribute "complexityType" equals to "juxtaposition", but I don't know how to nest multiple query to retrieve multiple informations about the same elements.
I tried the | operator but it's an AND, so it gives me all the names of the images if I write something like this `....... | /root/image/info/name/text()`.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the `<image>` nodes with reqd complexityType.

```
/image[rhetoric/framework_1/complexity[@complexityType = 'juxtaposition']]
```

Then you combine that with the info/name.

```
/image[rhetoric/framework_1/complexity[@complexityType = 'juxtaposition']]/info/name/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

With XPath 2.0, you can use this to get all image names from your XML which respect your complexity type condition :

```
string-join(//complexity[@complexityType="juxtaposition"]/preceding::name,";")
```

Test it here.
https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

The output will look like :

"name of the first image; name of the second image; etc..."

Alternative : use XMLstarlet (supports XPath 1.0) and remove the `string-join()` part from the expression I've posted.